# how to play spotify media in android jni

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, spotify

I'm trying to create a simple player in android following guidance from http://damienradtke.org/playing-with-the-spotify-api/ , using it i'm able to play a track from spotify in ubuntu but i cant even build on android. So far i'm able to query for a track from spotify but its been a nightmare when i've tried to add playback capabilities using ALSA. I've tried using openAl and am still stuck.
Is there a much simpler way to play streamed audio in jni?

at the end of my &on_search_complete callback i call a function 'play' which looks like this:

```
void play(sp_session *session, sp_track *track)
{
if(DEBUG_MODE) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "spotify", "attempting to play track...");
sp_error error = sp_session_player_load(session, track);
    if (error != SP_ERROR_OK) {
    if(DEBUG_MODE) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "spotify", "Error: %s\n",    sp_error_message(error));
    exit(1);
}

if(DEBUG_MODE) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "spotify", "Playing...");
sp_session_player_play(session, 1);
}
```

this leads to the &on_music_delivery callback being executed, i believe this is where i need to add my playback code.

```
static int on_music_delivery(sp_session *session, const sp_audioformat *format, const void *frames, int num_frames)
{
if(DEBUG_MODE) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "spotify", "in on_music_delivery");
}
```

I've had little success building my code with ALSA, can someone point me to the right direction here. Its frustrating and i dont want to give up at the last hurdle.
NB: i'm a beginner in the C language

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work for Spotify*

First of all, I'd like to state that the Android documentation shipped with libspotify isn't nearly as great as it could be. We're working to improve this. Until then, I can advise you that using OpenSL to play audio from the native code is probably the easiest way to accomplish this task. I would advise checking out [this StackOverflow question to find some good OpenSL tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763149/tutorials-for-opensl-es-for-android).