# How to play sound or music from C in Android without java?

Tags: android, mobile, game-engine

Possible play sound or music from buffer without Java code? Use only Android NDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something called OpenSL ES you could use from C that does music.

Answer (score 1):

Use OpenSL. See:

- [Tutorials for OpenSL ES for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763149/tutorials-for-opensl-es-for-android)
- http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/android-audio-streaming-with-opensl-es-and-the-ndk/
- http://www.crickettechnology.com/blog/?p=201

and other resources.