# android:How to set tempo and pitch of play list using Media Player? Play list is playing in loop

Tags: android, audio, media-player

> android:How to set tempo and pitch of play list using Media Player?
>   Play list is  playing in loop.

Comment: I have used PlayBackParam

Answer (score 0):

To Change the tempo and pitch of playlist Make Use of **setPlaybackParams (PlaybackParams params)**  Method in MediaPlayer Class

***Reference:***

- [Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setPlaybackParams%28android.media.PlaybackParams%29)
- [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37094364/5740760)